# Why doesn't a Fragment directly implement its associated activity's method, rather than using an interface?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am reading ["Communicating with Other Fragments"](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Implement)

It writes:

> To allow a Fragment to communicate up to its Activity, you can define
>   an interface in the Fragment class and implement it within the
>   Activity. The Fragment captures the interface implementation during
>   its onAttach() lifecycle method and can then call the Interface
>   methods in order to communicate with the Activity.

My questions is:

Why doesn't a Fragment directly implement its associated activity's method, rather than using an interface?
What are advantages to use an interface as a media between Fragment and its associated Activity?

For example, another alternative of communication can be: in the Fragment class, in the onListItemClick(), I may directly use activity.onArticleSelected(position), rather than mCallback.onArticleSelected(position);

Comment: Because Java doesn't support partial classes, like C# does.

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry I do not understand about partial classes. In my understanding, another alternative of communication can be: in the Fragment class, in the onListItemClick(), I may directly use activity.onArticleSelected(position), rather than mCallback.onArticleSelected(position);

Comment: I wanted to know this as well. I'm guessing it's because Fragments are designed to be modular, reusable components. Fragments have a similar, but not identical lifecycle to that of an Activity. Since they can be removed, replaced, etc at any given time during the lifecycle of the Activity, it makes more sense to pass the data up to the Activity first and then to any other fragments that need the data. Hopefully we can get some more insight on this though.

Comment: Thanks. However, mCallback in Fragment still depends on the lifecycle of the Activity. So I do not see any difference here.

Answer (score 0):

In some case,the fragment may lost association with the activity.I came across the special exception when using file choosers.In this case,you can't find any activity according the fragment.So Google may want you do the right things only in fragment's onAttach() Taclifecycle.